# Libcurl: Using libcurl, is it possible to create a list of GET requests for the same easy handle?

Tags: c, curl, libcurl

I am using Libcurl and multi interface to write a program.

Essentially this is what I would like to do:

- Create a easy handle, set up the connection and send 1 GET request.
- Once the response is received, use the same handle and send 2 GET
  requests.
- After I get response for those, send 3 GET requests    simultaneously
  and so on.

I would also like to:

- Send multiple GET requests in an incremental order based on timeout.
  I.e If I have sent 3 GET requests, after a second I would like to send 4 requests irrespective of whether I have received the response using the same connection handle.

I know about Pipeling feature so I use that for other use case but I can't use that to do the above.
Is there a way to do this using Libcurl?

Comment: libcurl is a lockstep communication, usually using TCP.  However, it can only wait for a single response, so No, there is no way to do this with a single handle.

Comment: I'm sure this is the same person who also posted to the libcurl mailing list, where we sorted out more details and cleared a few misconceptions: http://curl.haxx.se/mail/lib-2014-09/0104.html